# How to insert a character after the first byte in a line in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed

I have a setting file states `1,2,3` meaning to place a `,` after the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd **byte**.

For example my input is

```
stackoverflow
```

then I want to make it

```
s,t,a,ckoverflow
```

How should I do it with Linux tools? I feel `sed` should be used, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit:

I have more than 10 commas to be placed. And the line also includes multi-byte characters.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your new information about multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`:

```
echo stackoverflow | sed 's/./&,/1;s/./&,/3;s/./&,/5'
```

`s/.../.../n` replaces the *n*th match. After the first replacement, the second byte would now be the third match, and after that, the third byte would now be the fifth.

Or, with regex groups:

```
echo stackoverflow | sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1,\2,\3,/'
```

In Basic Regular Expressions (BRE), `\(…\)` is used to group expressions. You can refer to the text that matched the *n*th group using `\n`, to re-use matched text in the replacement, for example. So, in this case, I have three groups, each containing just `.`.

With GNU sed, you can avoid the `\` by using Extended Regular Expressions (ERE):

```
echo stackoverflow | sed -r 's/(.)(.)(.)/\1,\2,\3,/'
```

With multibyte charsets, try with the C locale:

```
$ echo 'æ  ' | LC_ALL=C sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1,\2,\3,/'
�,�, , 
$ echo → | LC_ALL=C sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1,\2,\3,/'
�,�,�,
```

Comment: @hek2mgl `LC_ALL=C sed ...`, perhaps?

Comment: How does that change the input charset?

Comment: @hek2mgl it doesn't, but it does make `sed`  see incoming characters as a byte wide: `echo → | LC_ALL=C sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1,\2,\3,/'`

Comment: Oh, never knew that `sed` changes this behaviour depending on `LC_` variables.

Comment: Can you explain what does `s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1,\2,\3,/` mean?

Comment: I found that sed only supports \1 through \9. I have more than 10 sets, so sed cannot meet my need.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$1"
rules=()
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    rules[$i]=1
done

s=stackoverflow
for (( i=0; i<${#s}; i++ )); do
    if (( ${rules[i+1]} )); then
        printf '%s,' "${s:i:1}"
    else
        printf '%s' "${s:i:1}"
    fi
done
```

Usage example:

```
$ ./sof 1,2,3
$ s,t,a,ckoverflow
$ ./sof 1,2,3,7
$ s,t,a,ckov,erflow
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B/\n/g;s/\n//4g;s/\n/,/g' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/\B/,/;s/\B/,/;s/\B/,/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative without using `sed` that can handle multi-byte characters and more than 10 commas.

```
S="♥stackoverflow"
I="1,2,11"
i=0
for j in `echo $I | tr ',' '\n'`; do
   printf ${S:i:j-i}
   i=$j
done
printf ${S:i}
```

This script has the following output:

```
♥,s,tackoverf,low
```

With `I="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"` the output is:

```
♥,s,t,a,c,k,o,v,e,r,f,low
```